# Página web para compartir codigo o script

Tags: php, javascript, asp, script

Alguien sabe de alguna página web para compartir código o scripts, PHP, ASP, javascript, y demás.

Comment: Hola te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], por favor termina el [tour] :)

Comment: Esta pregunta en [meta] te puede dar una guía: [Lista de páginas que podemos usar para probar código y sus características](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2446/22721)

Comment: Hola Markus, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio). Esta pregunta no se ajusta bien al formato/contenido del sitio y por eso fue cerrada. Lee [ask] para más Información.

Answer (score 2):

Actualmente hay diversas plaformas para compartir codigo, como por ejemplo:

1. [GitHub](https://github.com/) (para mi es la mejor actualmente)
2. [Cloud9](http://cloud9.gg/) (era gratis y era super trabajar ahi hasta que la compro amazon)
3. [CodeAnyWhere](https://codeanywhere.com/) (es algo que tiene una interfaz muy similar a Sublime text)
4. [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/product) (el mismo contexto que GitHub pero más privado)
5. [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) (similar a Github)

y tambien en google encontraras muchas otras, estas son las que yo he usado.

ReNiceCode....

Comment: No todas las preguntas pueden o deben responderse. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que solicitan opiniones en vez de realidades, o que no tratan sobre programación o desarrollo tal y como lo definimos en el centro de ayuda. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Ok maestro, solo que la asumi que la pregunta merecia un respuesta ya que es algo necesario en la programacion

Comment: Esto es claramente una pregunta demasiado amplia, basada en opiniones, y no es un problema concreto de programación. Este tipo de preguntas es más apropiado para el chat (aunque comprendo que el usuario no tiene suficiente reputación para entrar) que para el sitio. Lee [answer] y [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](/help/dont-ask) para más información.